# sql : avoid usauge of cartesian product

Tags: sql, oracle

can somebody help optimize Cartesian product as it takes a lot of time to execute:

```
select c_msg.gft_id,
       a_msg.pkSize
from   Gifts c_msg,
       (select   giftContId,
                 count(*) pkSize
        from     Gifts gft
        GROUP BY gft.giftContId) a_msg 
where  sentDate between (sysdate-10) and (sysdate-1)
and    a_msg.giftContId = c_msg.giftContId
order by a_msg.giftId;
```

Comment: The obvious solution would be to add a join condition using an `ON` clause.  That being said, is there any way to join these two tables?

Comment: It doesn't make much sense. Gifts.giftId is not unique? have you meant to use another table? and pkgSize, what does it stands for?

Comment: Please edit your question and add table structure with information what is the unique identifier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure this works on Oracle. In postgresql, you can do something like this:

```
SELECT gft_id, count(*) over (partition by giftContId) as pkSize
FROM Gifts
WHERE sentDate between (sysdate-10) and (sysdate-1)
ORDER BY giftId;
```

Comment: Yes it is correct syntax for Oracle and it looks query do what OP needs.